# Why are the newline and the white space treated differently in the lexer specification?

Tags: f#, lexer, fslex

I am using F#'s FsLex to generate a lexer.  I have difficulties to understand the following two lines from a textbook. Why is the newline (\n) treated differently from the white space?  In particular, what does "lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine" do differently from "Tokenize lexbuf"?

```
rule Tokenize = parse
  | [' ' '\t' '\r'] { Tokenize lexbuf }
  | '\n'            { lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine; Tokenize lexbuf }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `rule` is essentially a function that takes a lexer buffer as an argument.  Each case on the left side of your rule *matches* a given character (e.g., `'\n'`) or class of characters (`[' ' '\t' '\r']`) in your input.  The expression on the right size of the rule, inside the curly braces `{ ... }`, defines an *action*.  The purpose of the definition you pasted in appears to be a *tokenizer*.

The expression `Tokenize lexbuf` is a recursive call to the `Tokenize` rule.  In essence, this rule ignores whitespace character.  Why?  Because tokenizers aim to simplify the input.  Whitespace typically has no meaning in a programming language, so this rule filters it out.  Tokenized input generally makes writing your parser simpler later on.  You'll eventually want to add other cases to your `Tokenize` rule (e.g., for keywords, assignment statements, and other expressions) to produce a complete lexer definition.

The second rule, the one that matches `\n`, also ignores the whitespace, but as you correctly point out, it does something different.  What it's doing is updating the position of the end of the line (`lexbuf.EndPos`) with the position of the *next line's end* (`lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine`) before recursively calling `Tokenize` again.  Why?  Presumably so that the end position is correct on the next recursive call.

Since you're only showing a lexer fragment here, I can only guess as to what `lexbug.EndPos` is used for, but it's pretty common to keep that information around for diagnostic purposes.